# H2 refers to wrong table

Tags: java, h2, liquibase, dbunit, integration-testing

I did a bit of refactoring in my code and also in database. One of the changes I did  in DB was to create a new table `newTable1` which contains some of information of `oldTable2`, and from some othere tables. Then I dropped `oldTable2` and  renamed table `newTable1` to `oldTable2`

In my local database, everything works perfectly. The problem I have is with integration testing. It looks like tests still refers to the old table instead to the new one.

And also when my entity refers to: `@Table(name = "oldTable2")` - the tests work, but the applications don't not. When I change it to `@Table(name = "newTable1")` - the tests don't work , but applications do.

I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Column "TABLE0_.ID" not found; SQL statement:
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.optimize(ExpressionColumn.java:147)
at org.h2.expression.Alias.optimize(Alias.java:51)
at org.h2.command.dml.Select.prepare(Select.java:835)
at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:246)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareLocal(Session.java:460)
at org.h2.engine.Session.prepareCommand(Session.java:402)
```

Sorry for the messy explanation and thank you for any clues.

Comment: Well, it's looking for table0, not table1, so, are you sure you're not confused?